# Padding ascii characters with spaces in a mix unicode-ascii string

Tags: python, regex, unicode, ascii

Given a mixed string of unicode and ascii chars, e.g.:

```
它看灵魂塑Nike造得和学问同等重要。
```

The goal is to pad the ascii substrings with spaces, i.e.:

```
它看灵魂塑 Nike 造得和学问同等重要。
```

I've tried using the `([^[:ascii:]])` regex,  it looks fine in matching the substrings, e.g. https://regex101.com/r/FVHhU1/1

But in code, the substitution with `' \1 '` is not achieving the desired output.

```
>>> import re
>>> patt = re.compile('([^[:ascii:]])')
>>> s = u'它看灵魂塑Nike造得和学问同等重要。'
>>> print (patt.sub(' \1 ', s))
它看灵魂塑Nike造得和学问同等重要。
```

**How to pad ascii characters with spaces in a mix unicode-ascii string?**

Comment: Just saying, but if you had set regex101 to python mode, you'd have noticed that this doesn't work in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern should be:

```
([\x00-\x7f]+)
```

So you can use:

```
patt = re.compile('([\x00-\x7f]+)')
patt.sub(r' \1 ',s)
```

This generates:

```
>>> print(patt.sub(r' \1 ',s))
它看灵魂塑 Nike 造得和学问同等重要。
```

ASCII is defined as a range of characters with hex codes between `00` and `7f`. So we define such a range as `[\x00-\x7f]`, use `+` to denote *one or more*, and replace the matching group with `r' \1 '` to add two spaces.